# overwrite column values using other column values based on conditions pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a `data frame` in `pyspark` like below.

`df.show()`

```
+-----------+------------+-------------+
|customer_id|product_name|      country|
+-----------+------------+-------------+
|   12870946|        null|       Poland|
|     815518|       MA401|United States|
|    3138420|     WG111v2|           UK|
|    3178864|    WGR614v6|United States|
|    7456796|       XE102|United States|
|   21893468|     AGM731F|United States|
+-----------+------------+-------------+
```

I have another data frame like below
`df1.show()`

```
+-----------+------------+
|customer_id|product_name|
+-----------+------------+
|   12870946|     GS748TS|
|     815518|       MA402|
|    3138420|        null|
|    3178864|    WGR614v6|
|    7456796|       XE102|
|   21893468|     AGM731F|
|       null|       AE171|
+-----------+------------+
```

Now I want to do a `fuller outer join` on these tables and update `product_name` column values like below.

```
1) Overwrite the values in `df` using values in `df1` if there are values in `df1`.
2) if there are `null` values or `no` values in `df1` then leave the values in `df` as they are
```

`expected result`

```
+-----------+------------+-------------+
|customer_id|product_name|      country|
+-----------+------------+-------------+
|   12870946|     GS748TS|       Poland|
|     815518|       MA402|United States|
|    3138420|     WG111v2|           UK|
|    3178864|    WGR614v6|United States|
|    7456796|       XE102|United States|
|   21893468|     AGM731F|United States|
|       null|       AE171|         null|
+-----------+------------+-------------+
```

I have done like below

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df2 = df.join(df1, df.customer_id == df1.customer_id, 'full_outer').select(df.customer_id, f.coalesce(df.product_name, df1.product_name).alias('product_name'), df.country)
```

But the result I am getting is different

`df2.show()`

```
+-----------+------------+-------------+
|customer_id|product_name|      country|
+-----------+------------+-------------+
|   12870946|        null|       Poland|
|     815518|       MA401|United States|
|    3138420|     WG111v2|           UK|
|    3178864|    WGR614v6|United States|
|    7456796|       XE102|United States|
|   21893468|     AGM731F|United States|
|       null|       AE171|         null|
+-----------+------------+-------------+
```

How can I get the `expected result`

Comment: The code you provided works for me. Are you sure that you have actual `null` values and not the string `"null"` in your dataframe?

Comment: @pault they are `null` values `Not null` strings and I am unable to get my desired result. Could you please provide the results when you run the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you wrote produces the correct output for me, so I can not reproduce your problem. I have seen other posts where using an alias when doing joins has resolved issues so here is a slightly modified version of your code which will do the same thing:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.alias("r").join(df1.alias("l"), on="customer_id", how='full_outer')\
    .select(
        "customer_id",
        f.coalesce("r.product_name", "l.product_name").alias('product_name'),
        "country"
    )\
    .show()
#+-----------+------------+-------------+
#|customer_id|product_name|      country|
#+-----------+------------+-------------+
#|    7456796|       XE102|United States|
#|    3178864|    WGR614v6|United States|
#|       null|       AE171|         null|
#|     815518|       MA401|United States|
#|    3138420|     WG111v2|           UK|
#|   12870946|     GS748TS|       Poland|
#|   21893468|     AGM731F|United States|
#+-----------+------------+-------------+
```

I get the same results when I run your code as well (reproduced below):

```python
df.join(df1, df.customer_id == df1.customer_id, 'full_outer')\
    .select(
        df.customer_id,
        f.coalesce(df.product_name, df1.product_name).alias('product_name'),
        df.country
    )\
    .show()
```

I am using spark 2.1 and python 2.7.13.

Comment: looks like the data was corrupted I got the desired result when I manually created the `data frames` and then ran your code and my code both gave me correct result

Answer (score 3):

*Your code is perfect if the values are not string null*. But looking at the df2 dataframe you are getting *the values in `product_name` seem to be string null*. You will have to check for *string null* using `when` *inbuilt function* and `isnull` *inbuilt funtion* as

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df2 = df.join(df1, df.customer_id == df1.customer_id, 'full_outer')\
    .select(df.customer_id, f.when(f.isnull(df.product_name) | (df.product_name == "null"), df1.product_name).otherwise(df.product_name).alias('product_name'), df.country)
df2.show(truncate=False)
```

which should give you

```
+-----------+------------+------------+
|customer_id|product_name|country     |
+-----------+------------+------------+
|7456796    |XE102       |UnitedStates|
|3178864    |WGR614v6    |UnitedStates|
|815518     |MA401       |UnitedStates|
|3138420    |WG111v2     |UK          |
|12870946   |GS748TS     |Poland      |
|21893468   |AGM731F     |UnitedStates|
|null       |AE171       |null        |
+-----------+------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there are some conflicting reports - first just create a new column in df1 with the column from df2 you want to use, assuming you df's are of the same dimensions, or join them as necessary if not.Then you can use SQL conditionals.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df1 = df1.withColumn('column', F.when(df1['column'].isNull(), df1['column']).otherwise(df1['other-column-originally-from-df2']) )
```

Comment: I am getting the below error `pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'resolved attribute(s) product_name#9 missing from customer_id#11,product_name#12 in operator !Project [customer_id#11,product_name#12,CASE WHEN isnull(product_name#12) THEN product_name#9 ELSE product_name#12 AS model#13];'` I have done like below `df2 = df1.withColumn('model', f.when(df1['product_name'].isNull(), df['product_name']).otherwise(df1['product_name']))`

Comment: You can't refer to another DataFrame when you are working on one. i.e : df.withColumn("X1", df1[...]) is not correct.